# Freya - Switch File Manager to Luna's

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files, file-management

I've used Luna for a couple of years, and I got used to Luna's File Manager. The way we search for a file is similar to nautilus. We type, the search bar is at the bottom, and the first occurence of the file is selected. We can then press Tab, and navigate with the arrows. On Freya, this is different.

The search bar is mixed with the path's bar. This is horrible because if we want to clear our search string, holding backspace, once it clears all the characters, it starts moving us to the parent directory. Also, all the occurences of the search are selected as we type.

I really can't get used to it. Is there a way to downgrade the file manager to the version used in Luna?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: No. Luna's version of Pantheon Files depends on libraries that are not available in Freya (or, to be more specific, the corresponding version of a library is not available anymore).

Pantheon Files has undergone a lot of development since Luna anyway, so you would be losing crucial bug fixes.

Comment: I believe so. But there are some details I cannot get used to.